# 403 when pushing to Github (using https)

Tags: git, github

Git/Github does *not* ask me for username/password at the command line, when I was hoping that it would! Notice that this is the opposite question of "why is git/Github asking for my username/password"?

Here is the sequence:

```
$ git push
remote: Permission to userEFGH/cagor.git denied to userABCD.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/userEFGH/cagor.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

So apparently I am logged in as the wrong user? I don't have any ssh keys configured on this machine, so why wouldn't git/Github then give me an opportunity to use username/password?

As you can see, git/Github thinks I am `userABCD`. I am trying to push to a repo owned by `userEFGH`.

But why does git/Github think I am `userABCD`, when I don't have any ssh keys on this machine? I have also never run `git config --global x`, TMK.

Just as an aside, I have two Github accounts, one is for userABCD and the other is userEFGH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that git's configurations on your machine *thinks* that you're userABCD, to check this use the command `git config --list` this will show what user.name and user.email you're using. If userABCD is shown then you can change it with `git config user.email userEFGH@email.domain`, if you want this globally changed (meaning git in general and not just in your local repo) use `git config --global user.email userEFGH@your.domain` 
Hope this helps you and/or others